# Parse CSV into multiple lines where each value is printed after its header

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hashtable

Using Ruby 1.9.2 I need to parse a CSV file, and output lines with each header key and individual value paired together, with line numbers.

header: key1, key2, key3
row1: a, b, c
row2: d, , f

expected output:

1
key1 a
key2 b
key3 c

2

key1 d
key2
key3 f

Right now working on just combining the header with the values, and I'm failing pretty hard.

```
require 'csv'

header = File.open('TEXT.CSV', &:readline) 
keys = header.split(",")


values = CSV.read("TEXT.CSV")

def combine(a,b)
  zipped = a.zip(b)
  Hash[zipped]
end

keyvalue = values.each do |i|
  combine(keys,i)
end
```

Any ideas what I did wrong in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'csv'
lineN = 0

CSV.read( filename  ).each do |arr|
  if lineN == 0
    headers = arr
  else
    puts "line #{lineN}"

    headers.zip(arr).each do |a|
      puts "#{a.first} : #{a.last}"
    end
  end
  lineN += 1
end
```

creates:

```
line 1
key1 : a
key2 : b
key3 : c

line 2
key1 : d
key2 : 
key3 : f
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a more easy way:

```
require 'csv'
csv = CSV.read('branch.csv', :headers => true)
csv.each do |line|
  puts csv.headers.zip(line.fields)
end

# =>    
key1
a
key2
b
key3
c
key1
d
key2

key3
f
```